# SoapUI becomes unresponsive after starting on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, soapui

Mac OS version: Sierra, 10.12.3
SoapUI version: 5.3.0

Steps to reproduce:

- Launch SoapUI
- Wait a few seconds
- The mouse cursor turns into a colourwheel
- Activity monitor shows the SoapUI process as not responding: need to kill the process to quit the app.

Answer (score 11):

Found a solution here:

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/SoapUI-Pro-5-1-2-hangs-on-Mac-OS-X-10-8-5/td-p/95626

```
cd /Applications/SoapUI-5.3.0.app/Contents
```

In file `java/app/bin/soapui.sh` uncomment line 66:

```
65 # uncomment to disable browser component
66     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"
```

In file `vmoptions.txt` add the following line:

```
-Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true
```

*Note*
This will disable "test on demand"

Comment: Didn't work for me either, still hangs. There is one suggestion to change java runtime environment to 1.8, which didn't work for me either. I remember months ago deleting some file helped me, but I can't find this solution anymore. What a terrible app.

Comment: Editing `soapui.sh` didn't work for me, but editing `vmoptions.txt` (it's directly in `Contents`, not in `java/app/bin`) *did*. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me with a caveat. I have to go to /Applications/SoapUI-<ver>/Contents/java/app/bin and run `sh soapui.sh` from the command line to run it. If i open it from desktop it crashes after starting up.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can navigate to `SoapUI*.app`, right-click and select "*Show Package Info*" (from popup menu). Then you should see `Contents` directory; open `Info.plist` and add the following lines:

```
<key>soapui.jxbrowser.disable</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: This worked for 1 min before getting stuck again. The app used to be usable before, it has become unusable now.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It hangs right after prompting for consent to allow incoming connections to non-standard ports. So not sure if it has something to do with permissions  / configurations.